# Customizing opentripplanner webapp

Tags: openlayers-2, maps, transit

I am using opentripplanner for an app development. I want to customize the webapp. It has many different maplayers (its using openlayers). I want to change some mapslayers, but i couldn't find in which java-script file they are creating map and maplayers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The entry point for adding map layers is in the
>   [Controller](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/blob/master/opentripplanner-webapp/src/main/webapp/js/otp/application/Controller.js).
>   On line 56, the map controller is created:
>
> ```
> this.map = new otp.core.Map(this.config.map);
> ```
>
> Calling `this.map.getMap()`, will give you the OpenLayers.Map object.
>   You're on your own from here, as we haven't really built api support
>   for adding new layers to the map.

This answer was found [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/opentripplanner-dev/rJuDIVWgp_s/bDOf53Ce4Z4J) and modified a little bit.